# Trying to re-define += in an Array subclass doesn't seem to do anything?

Tags: ruby, arrays, concatenation

In an Array subclass (just an array that does some coercing of input values) I've defined `#concat` to ensure values are coerced.  Since nobody ever uses `#concat` and is more likely to use `#+=` I tried to alias `#+=` to `#concat`, but it never seems to get invoked.  Any ideas?

Note that the coercing is actually always to objects of a particular superclass (which accepts input via the constructor), in case this code seems not to do what I describe.  It's part of an internal, private API.

```
  class CoercedArray < Array
    def initialize(type)
      super()
      @type = type
    end

    def push(object)
      object = @type.new(object) unless object.kind_of?(@type)
      super
    end

    def <<(object)
      push(object)
    end

    def concat(other)
      raise ArgumentError, "Cannot append #{other.class} to #{self.class}<#{@type}>" unless other.kind_of?(Array)
      super(other.inject(CoercedArray.new(@type)) { |ary, v| ary.push(v) })
    end

    alias :"+=" :concat
  end
```

`#concat` is working correctly, but `#+=` seems to be completely by-passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `a += b` is syntactic sugar for `a = a + b` I'd try to overwrite the `+` method.